# I am searching for a word/name that fits a person that has the ability to swap bodies with another human

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, short-story

Not to be confused with a person who can morph themselves into someone else or a creature by will, but someone who has an ability to body swap - without necessarily having control over it. I am writing a short fiction story and I am looking for acceptable sounding names/words to describe this action and the scientific name for body swapping. I have come across Changeling, Morphling, and Automorphic but all of these suggest a way of having control over of changing one's own physical appearance. I am looking for something more specific to the actual switching of bodies.

Comment: The English and ELL stack exchanges often have questions along for words and phrases that have specific meanings.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is a real word for this. I would use "swapper."

I chose swapper over a number of alternatives. The closest one, to me, is "jumper."

However, a swapper, to me, jumps to a new body and that body's mind jumps to the former body. Notice that the normal person's mind is now stuck in this body forever, unless he can find and force the swapper to put him back.

A jumper, on the other hand, feels like it would jump to another body and one of two things would happen: the old body would just drop dead because it has no consciousness, or the original consciousness would "wake up" (maybe not immediately) and take over it's original body again. It would depend of if the jumper destroys the consciousness or suppresses it.

I am trying to remember the book in which a group of swappers existed. I believe it was in the Wild Cards series. These swappers were eventually captured and forced to put people right again. Then they were put into old/sickly bodies and put in a prison farther away from people than the range of their power.

Comment: You could likely improve on this answer with an [Edit] to discuss why you prefer "swapper" over any alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Body swapping does not (yet) exist, so there cannot be, as you ask for, a *scientific* term for it. But you can make one up.

In Latin, "to exchange, to swap" is *permutare* and "body" is *corpus*, so the scientific term for a "body-changer" could be a *corpopermutant* or *corpo-permutant* or briefly a ***permutant***, while the common folk would probably call them swappers, as NomadMaker has suggested..

Answer (score 3):

There is one Latin book from 1670s, Speculum carmelitanum, that calls this "corporislatro", thief-of-the-body.

Although the Latin name is ugly, perhaps "body thief" would catch up.

Comment: Interesting. Can you give a page number? I can't find the term in the book...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much to everyone for their suggestions. I went with a different direction. I did some research and made up a name and origin to fit my needs for this story. I can't post what I went with because I made it up myself and this story is not finished. But this is the research I used----
Name origin: Latin - Vicarius; substitute, proxy, to live through another. Origin: Nordic/Gaelic folklore. Derived from Scandinavian Changelings and the Seilie Court (Scottish Faries).

I would like to close this post as I have found my answer but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Award the answer to one of the answers. In your case, probably your own.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just go with 'Switcher'

Or maybe 'Jumper'

Comment: Hi Paresh, and welcome. You could improve this answer by an [Edit] that discusses why you prefer "switcher" or "jumper" to other alternatives. Answers that provide some rationale tend to be better received than those that just provide a suggestion but not the reasoning behind it.